# Object prototypes and Inheritance

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

```
// the original Animal class and sayName method
function Animal(name, numLegs) {
    this.name = name;
    this.numLegs = numLegs;
}
Animal.prototype.sayName = function() {
    console.log("Hi my name is " + this.name);
};

// define a Penguin class
function Penguin() {
    this.name = "penguin";
    this.numLegs = 2;
}

// set its prototype to be a new instance of Animal
var penguin = new Animal("Penguin", 2);

penguin.sayName();
```

The compiler asks me to "Create a new Penguin instance called penguin"...

not sure what I'm doing wrong here

Comment: `// set its prototype to be a new instance of Animal`, that doesn't look right. You are creating an instance of animal, there is no inheritance going on there.

Comment: Which compiler? Which prototype and inheritance ? You just create an instance of `Animal` and assign it to the `penguin`. From your code, it is easy to see that `penguin.sayName();` would write to the console, "Hi my name is Penguin".

Comment: I would avoid using the term class for JavaScript. Js doesn't have classes really...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to make a Penguin object that inherits from Animal using prototypal inheritance in javascript:

```
// the original Animal class and sayName method
function Animal(name, numLegs) {
    this.name = name;
    this.numLegs = numLegs;
}
Animal.prototype.sayName = function() {
    console.log("Hi my name is " + this.name);
};


// define a Penguin class
function Penguin() {
    this.name = "penguin";
    this.numLegs = 2;
}
// set its prototype to be a new instance of Animal
Penguin.prototype = new Animal();


// Create new Penguin
var penguin = new Penguin();

penguin.sayName(); // outputs "Hi my name is penguin"
var legCount = penguin.numLegs; // outputs 2
```

Here's an article that explains JavaScript Prototypal Inheritance in detail:
http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/09/JavaScript-Prototypal-Inheritence-Explained-in-Simple-Terms

Comment: This is one old way of doing inheritance I guess, not ideal though.

Comment: @elclanrs Old way? Please explain how standard prototypal inheritance in JavaScript is no ideal?

Comment: `new Animal` could have side-effects, so yeah, not ideal. Ideally today you'd use `Penguin.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype)`, then setup the constructor `Penguin.prototype.constructor = Animal`.

Comment: @elclanrs Awesome, thanks! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FObject%2Fcreate